# Allure get all failed tests from previous time

Tags: automation, testng, allure

For example, I have got 1000 automated tests. Yesterday 700 were passed and 300 were failed. Today we have 680 passed and 320 failed.

Is it possible to get these 20 new failed tests without checking all of them manually?

Answer (score 0):

New failed tests are marked with an icon.

[image: New failed tests icon]

More details on github issue [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/858).